# Проблема валидаций во VUE

Tags: vue.js

Проблема валидаций во VUE. Вроде всё прописал но не работает и в консоль ни какие ошибки не выдаёт. Хотел чтобы при отсутствии текста в форме добавлял класс, если без бутстрапа начинаются ошибки, если его добавить ошибок нет но всё равно ничего не работает. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      formReg: {
        lName: ''
      },
    }
  },
  validations: {
    formReg: {
      lName: {
        required
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="l-name">
      <label for="l-name">Фамилия: </label><br>
      <input 
      @blur="$v.formReg.lName.$touch()"
      :class="{'is-invalids': $v.formReg.lName.$error}" 
      v-model="formReg.lName" 
      type="text" id="l-name"><b>*</b>
</div
```

Comment: Использую vualidate, в этом примере подключил бутстрап

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Импортируйте `import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'`

Укажите `v-model="$v.formReg.lName.$model"`

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не произошло, импортировал в main.js. Добавил v-model и не ошибок и не добавления класса

Comment: Самое интересное что в инспекте класс задаётся, но из css он не работает, что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Вот я дуб) Спасибо, всё заработало.